# How to append with a Python script in blender 2.78?

Tags: scripting, add-on, blend-files

I'm trying to modify a add-on so it could be better for me and the others but this line of code isn't working :

bpy.ops.wm.append(filepath="D:\libraries\Desktop\Desktop\Art\3D\Blender Stuff\2017\Shader\Group_Nodes.blend\NodeTree", directory="/NodeTree/", filename="Dynamat_Render")

How can i fix it?

Comment: what is the error appearing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a windows dir to me.
You have to escape backslashes with a backslash.
It's a Python thing:  https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

```
bpy.ops.wm.append(filepath="D:\\libraries\\Desktop\\Desktop\\Art\\3D\\Blender Stuff\\2017\\Shader\\Group_Nodes.blend\\NodeTree", directory="\\NodeTree\\", filename="Dynamat_Render")
```

Also:

```
directory="/NodeTree/"
```

...might cause errors as well.  You're switching to forward slashes here,
so it's a different format than the rest of your dir entry.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work also... I really don't know what to do.